# Run time error '3164': 'Field cannot be updated' - Access VBA issue

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I'm having an issue with a piece of VBA I've written for Access. I have a table with a concatenation field 'Concat' (string field) and field called 'Age' (integer field with numerical values).

There are another 61 fields (named '0','1','2'...'60' respectively) where the code needs to work though: I want the code to loop through and, per record entry - for the VBA to Dlookup using the Concat + age fields to another table (called: tbl_Final_Probabilities) and pull back a probability and populate each of these 61 fields with the correct probability. These fields are set up at a numerical field, data type as Single.

The code pulls the correct probability but when I try to update the record for that field at the code line: "rs.Fields(a) = b" (also highlighted in code), I get the error message: "Run time error '3164': 'Field cannot be updated'".

All help welcome on how I need to correct this please, the code used is below.

Punch and pie.

### Code:

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim a As Integer
Dim b As Single
Dim lookup As String

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tbl_Circuit_plus_prob")

For a = 0 To 60

    If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then
        rs.MoveFirst

            Do Until rs.EOF = True

            rs.Edit

            lookup = rs!Concat & (rs!age + a)

            b = DLookup("Prob_Date", "tbl_Final_Probabilities", "Concat2 = '" & lookup & "'")

            rs.Fields(a) = b  '- CODE BREAKS DOWN HERE

            rs.Update

            rs.MoveNext

            Loop

    End If

Next a

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
```

Thanks in advance for any and all help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You loop is turned inside out:

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim a As Integer
Dim b As Single
Dim lookup As String

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tbl_Circuit_plus_prob")

If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then
    rs.MoveFirst
    Do Until rs.EOF = True
        rs.Edit
        For a = 0 To 60
            lookup = rs!Concat & (rs!age + a)
            b = DLookup("Prob_Date", "tbl_Final_Probabilities", "Concat2 = '" & lookup & "'")
            rs.Fields(a).Value = b
        Next
        rs.Update
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
End If
rs.Close

Set rs = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code: rs.Fields(a) = b  addresses the field with the index 'a' (which is 0 in the first loop), in your table, this is probably an auto increment field and therefore cannot be updated. If you want to write in the fields with the names '0','1',...  use this syntax: rs.Fields(x + a) = b, where x is the number of fields+1 (because your loop starts with 0)  in the table existing before your field '0'.

Comment: Cheers - corrected for this and it worked! Didn't realise it was the indexed value behind the field. For interest, if I want to refer to the name of the field instead of it's indexed value, what syntax/formula should I use please?

Comment: You can use either `rst!Fields("NameOfField")` or `rst!NameOfField` or (if spaces or strange names) `rst![Name Of The Field]`.